# How can I change object's size according to the distance/depth in ARView/ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I am working in ARKit/RealityKit/Swift, If I keep one box near to the camera then it has a perfect size. But if I move it far from the camera e.g 1 or 2 meters far then it looks smaller. I want to keep its size same in the user's eyes/perception.

I have done some basic math on the Z coordinate of the object. e.g. if z = -0.9 and size = 0.5 meter then what will be new size if z = -2 or far. But it does not work.

```
//Sample code to get an idea 
let original = Position()
let origianlSize: Float = 0.5
let newPosition = Position() // Assume it is far from original position
let newSize = origianlSize * newPosition.z / original.z // New size is not proper
```

[image]

Comment: let newSize = origianlSize * original.z / newPosition.z
Have you tried this?

Comment: Yeah, It is not working @ArnabAhamedSiam

Comment: can you explain the result of your current code?

Comment: The result varies every time, Sometime I get a smaller box or bigger than original